# Copy-Paste Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, copy-paste, paste

After copying and pasting cell(s) (does not matter whether by keyboard shortcut or bar menu), pasting doesn't work properly. The result works like opposite of "copy down" function. If I am pasting into one row range, the value from row below is pasted. If I am pasting into more than one row range, the content of bottom row is copied to entire range.

It is happening only in one particular table (which is just too difficult to reconstruct).

I have no idea why this happened, seems I might have clicked some unfortunate keyboard shortcut, but I have no idea how to get it back. Reopening excel or deleting Personal.xlsb file didn't help.

Edit:
I tried to make the table as small as possible and realized that the copy-paste worked fine after deleting a certain number of columns. When I added new columns (to have the table like before), the copy-paste didn't work again.

Could it be a memory problem (the table is quite bulk)?

Comment: Are there any sheet_change events?

Comment: I don't have any macros in the file (so I guess no).

Comment: If you are copying formulas, that may also be a reason... try pasting values only (if you only need them)

Comment: It is happening for both values and formulas as well as simple pasting and pasting values only.